# $a$ and $b>5$ are natural numbers, $a:b$ gives a remainder $(b-5)$, what will be the remainder when $(2a+7):b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Question: $a$ and $b>5$ are natural numbers, $a:b$ gives a remainder $(b-5)$, what will be the remainder when $(2a+7):b$?

How to solve this?

Comment: Your notation is unusual.  Are you saying that the remainder on dividing $b$ by $a$ is $b-5$?  Thus, we'd have $b=a\times q +(b-5)$ with $0≤b-5<a$?

Comment: dividing $a$ by $b$ is b-5

Comment: "$:$" is taught as a division symbol (just like $\div$) in many parts of the world. In that case, $a:b$ would mean $\frac ab$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$a = kb+b-5,$$ for some integer $k$, we have $b\geq 5$ and $$2a+7 = 2kb+2b-10+7 = b(2k+1)+b-3$$

So a remainder is $b-3$.